# Is there an error in the indexing of omega?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, matrix-elements

[image: Book reference: Principles of Quantum Mechanics,R. Shankar]

The topic is matrix elements in linear operators. When I read through the text, I found that the indexing used for $\Omega $ did not match the results of matrix multiplication given at the bottom of the page. The author abruptly switched from $\Omega_{ji}$ (equation 1.6.1) to $ \Omega_{ij}$. I have tried correcting (written with pencil) the notation using the given definitions for transformation of $ |i> $ to $ |i'> $under $\Omega$ operator, but I am not sure whether what I have worked out is correct or not. Please have a look and let me know.

Comment: isnt $v_i'=<i|v'>$?

Comment: The author didn’t “abruptly” switch. The indices switched because $\langle i|\Omega|j\rangle$ appeared instead of $\langle j|\Omega|i\rangle$.

Comment: Your final equation $v_i’=\sum_iv_i\Omega_{ji}$ doesn’t make sense. It has a free index $i$ on the left and a free index $j$ on the right.

Comment: @G.Smith  I didn't understand the " free index " thing. can you please explain ?

Comment: An equation like $A_i=B_i$ is just shorthand for three separate equations, $A_1=B_1$, $A_2=B_2$, and $A_3=B_3$. The index $i$ is called “free” because it can be freely assigned to be any value 1, 2, or 3. An equation like $A_i=B_j$ doesn’t make sense. What would it mean?

Comment: @Wolphramjonny thank you. i totally blanked out on the part that |V ' > can also be expressed as a linear combination of  original basis | i >  as it is still a member of the same vector space and hence the inner product. :)

Comment: @G.Smith If i change \sum_{i} to \sum_{j} , then it'll make up for the free index i guess ?

Comment: No, just doing that wouldn’t be correct either. As far as I can tell, the book is doing it correctly.

Comment: @G.Smith yes, the textbook has no errors. thank you for answering.